# solving equation of circles

Tags: geometry, algebra-precalculus, solution-verification, analytic-geometry, circles

I have two points on a circle from which I want to find the center of the circle. I also know the radius $r$. I am trying to solve two equations but not able to find the centre $(C_x,C_y)$. Can someone check what I am doing wrong?

1. $(A_x - C_x)^2 + (A_y - C_y)^2 = r^2$
2. $(B_x - C_x)^2 + (B_y - C_y)^2 = r^2$

Solving 1 first, I got

$-C_x^2 = r^2 - A_x^2 - A_y^2 + C_y^2$

Putting this value in eq. 2, I got nothing ... how to find $C_x$ and $C_y$ then?

$B_x^2 - A_x^2 - A_y^2 + B_y^2 = 0$

these are the values I already know...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The initial equations you wrote are correct.  The problem is incorrectly squaring.

$$(a+b)^2=(a+b)(a+b)=a(a+b)+b(a+b)=a^2+ab+ba+b^2=a^2+2ab+b^2.$$

Similarly,

$$(a-b)^2=(a-b)(a-b)=a^2-2ab+b^2.$$

So, for example, $(A_x-C_x)^2=A_x^2-2A_xC_x+C_x^2$, not $A_x^2-C_x^2$.

If you subtract the equations, you will be left with a linear equation relating $C_x$ and $C_y$.  You could solve for one in terms of the other, then substitute back into one of the original equations.